# Using Mediawiki to Connect to a Custom Database?

Tags: database, mediawiki

I don't know if this is possible, and I know Mediawiki isn't designed to do this, but I haven't been able to really find any sort of information about this and fear I'm not using the right terminology. Is it possible to have a page on Mediawiki connect to a database? For example, let's say you have a table of information stored in a database on your server that lists a bunch of country data. Would there be a way for a Mediawiki page to grab information from that database, say using PHP, and output it as an HTML table? Like a traditional .php file that links to your mySQL tables and displays their information into an HTML table? Or do I have to use my PHP script to generate the table, then basically c/p the information in to Mediawiki?

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the right extension to use, I would say (though I'm biased because I wrote it): http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [write extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions) for MediaWiki in PHP, which may connect to your custom database.

Your case could be solved by a [Special Page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSpecial_pages) designed to grab exactly that country table, but you could also write a parser function hook or [tag extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions) to include the table (or any other table from that database?) in a usual wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

This extension should do it: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SQL2Wiki.